# Navigator.webkitPersistentStorage use in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to increase storage for the Chrome browser and am calling the above API as suggested in various sites. My source is in typescript. When the transpiler encounters this function below it throws this error -

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (..............)

*Property 'webkitPersistentStorage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.*

What is the appropriate import for this API. Is there a way around this. Please help.

Comment: Am I doing something incorrect, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the type.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957270/property-storage-does-not-exist-on-type-navigator) answer, I manually declared the `webkitPersistentStorage` property and any needed methods.

```
declare global {
    interface Navigator {
        webkitPersistentStorage: {
            requestQuota: (a, b, c) => {}
        }
    }
}
```

You could add any additional methods/parameters that you need based on this.

Comment: Let me check this, even though the workaround I used was to limit the rows returned to less than 3000, so that when converted to JSON, it will be less than the 5MB limitation. Thanks for your help.