# Property 'storage' does not exist on type 'Navigator'

Tags: typescript, indexeddb

I'm trying to get the quota storage information from an Angular2 component with this command line:

```
navigator.storage.estimate().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

The command works properly in a pure Javascript script but it doesn't get compiled in Angular2/Typescript.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify why this question involves indexedDB?

Comment: Hi Josh, cause the command above is used to get indexedDb quota storage information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find any available [@types](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) for the [StorageManager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager) interface.

My temporary solutions was to manually declare it in my code.

```
declare global {
  interface StorageEstimate {
    quota: number;
    usage: number;
  }
  interface Navigator {
    storage: {
      estimate: () => Promise<StorageEstimate>;
      persist: () => boolean;
      persisted: () => boolean;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is navigator ?  I guess it is a global variable on window without any type, so you should add a typing entry for this

https://github.com/typings/typings

Comment: is a browser object accessible throug Js